# FreeBSD's built-in ftpd and awstats

Tags: ftp, freebsd, awstats

How can I use awstats with the FreeBSD's built-in [ftpd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ftpd%288%29&sektion=)'s xferlog? Sample lines from `/var/log/xferlog` (simple syslog):

```
Sep 12 19:05:51 bsd-vps ftpd[35082]: connection from ###.###.###.###
Sep 12 19:05:52 bsd-vps ftpd[35082]: ANONYMOUS FTP LOGIN FROM ###.###.###.###, cfnetwork@apple.com
Sep 12 19:05:52 bsd-vps ftpd[35082]: session root changed to /usr/home/ftp/public
Sep 12 19:05:52 bsd-vps ftpd[35082]: get /homepage/stuff/math/jobs/kombinatorika_09.pdf = 115086 bytes (wd: /homepage/stuff/math/jobs; chrooted)
```

Comment: http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_faq.html#FTP

Comment: I know about it but the expected log format doesn't match. Or I missed something?